# R: Combinations based on ID

Tags: r, combinations

I want to create an edge list for a collaboration network. 
I have :

```
dat <- read.table(header=T, text="country ID1
China 1
France 1
Germany 1
'South Africa' 1
Canada 2
Germany 2
'United Kingdom' 2", stringsAsFactors=F)
```

And need (probably not the ID anymore):

```
China France 1
China Germany 1
China South Africa 1
France Germany 1
France South Africa 1
Germany South Africa 1
Canada Germany 2
Canada United Kingdom 2
Germany United Kingdom 2
```

Comment: You can check the `library(igraph)`

Comment: Thanks. I did of course and couldn't find what I search for. Otherwise I wouldn't be here. Its something like combn based on the ID but how exactly?

Comment: `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dat, dat$ID1), function(x) t(combn(x$country, 2))))` ... but seems rather long winded

Comment: THANKS! but with my table "countrytab" head looking like this:
country ID1
1          China   1
2         France   1
3        Germany   1
4   South Africa   1
5    Switzerland   1
6 United Kingdom   1

I get following error:  "Error in combn(x$country, 2) : n < m "

Comment: Marten, it's hard to see what you are posting. Can you edit your question with your code and error please. [ps: i have edited your question to show how i read it on - reasonable?]

Comment: Here is a rather clumsy `igraph` opption. Using `dat` in the question: `g = graph_from_data_frame(dat) ;
conn <- connect(g, 2) ;
as_data_frame(delete.vertices(conn, c("1" , "2")))`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps - although it is somewhat lengthy:

```
numID <- max(df1$ID1)
clist <- list()
for (i in 1:numID) {clist[[i]] <- t(combn(as.character(df1$country[df1$ID1==i]),2))}
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,clist))
#        V1             V2
# 1   China         France
# 2   China        Germany
# 3   China   South Africa
# 4  France        Germany
# 5  France   South Africa
# 6 Germany   South Africa
# 7  Canada        Germany
# 8  Canada United Kingdom
# 9 Germany United Kingdom
```

**data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(country = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 
6L), .Label = c("Canada", "China", "France", "Germany", "South Africa", 
"United Kingdom"), class = "factor"), ID1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("country", "ID1"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your end goal is to construct a bipartite network from the edgelist:

example data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(country = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 
6L), .Label = c("Canada", "China", "France", "Germany", "South Africa", 
"United Kingdom"), class = "factor"), ID1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("country", "ID1"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

conversion code:

```
library(network)
# construct a bipartite network
net_bp<-as.network(df1,matrix.type='edgelist',bipartite=2,directed=FALSE)
# print the rectangular bipartite network
as.matrix(net_bp)
  Canada China France Germany South Africa United Kingdom
1      0     1      1       1            1              0
2      1     0      0       1            0              1
# convert 1-mode projection on countries
tcrossprod( t(as.matrix(net_bp)) )
               Canada China France Germany South Africa United Kingdom
Canada              1     0      0       1            0              1
China               0     1      1       1            1              0
France              0     1      1       1            1              0
Germany             1     1      1       2            1              1
South Africa        0     1      1       1            1              0
United Kingdom      1     0      0       1            0              1
```

Some nice additional examples of working with bipartite networks at https://solomonmessing.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/working-with-bipartiteaffiliation-network-data-in-r/